# Cakephp 2.2.2 RSS not validate by w3 validator

Tags: cakephp, rss

I'm new in cakephp. So, I'm playing with it while learning and discover more things in cakephp.

I'm using cakephp 2.2.2 release. 
I would like to generate RSS feed for my website. So I followed 100% RSShelper tutorial here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/rss.html

But there's a problem with my generated RSS feed. W3's feed validation indicate that my RSS is not validate, here the result: [http://validator.w3.org/appc/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmalaysia60.info%2Fberitas%2Findex.rss](http://validator.w3.org/appc/check.cgi?url=http://malaysia60.info/beritas/index.rss)

I've no idea what's wrong. I've check and remove extra spaces in the View, RSS default layout and controller in cakephp files.

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this RSShelper. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this validation error because the XML declaration is missing from your RSS file. Add the following snippet to the top of your layout: `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and the error should go away.

Comment: I've tried to put the XML declaration in the RSS file but it's still not validate. Weird thing is, when I copy paste the source code of my RSS feed and put it to 'Validate by direct input', the RSS is validate.

Comment: Yes same validation error.In Mozilla, the feed display as normal Rss feed.

Comment: Hm, what happens if you serve the content as application/rss+xml?

Comment: It seems that I can't serve the content as you said. I've tried the instruction here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html but still cant render rss/xml file..do you know where to modified the content type in cakephp 2.2.2?

Comment: You can either use PHP's `header()` function or CakePHP's `$this->response->header()` method.

Comment: Thanks dhofstet..It's working! And I found something strange happens. When I remove one of the plugin, the RSS is working. It seems that one of the plugin's file I downloaded is the culprit.